# How to count no. of rows in a table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

suppose i want to count no rows in a table. but  if there is no id available. and nested table used.
so how to write xpath for  count no of rows .
i have tried

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@width='270']"));
System.out.println(list.size());
```

example: http://newtours.demoaut.com/
count no.of rows in a flights table.

thanks,

Comment: This won't compile. Next time, please provide code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two things wrong.

Firstly, you are using `.findElement` which will return the first element found matching the locator.

Secondly, you are just grabbing the `table`, and nothing else, nothing to do with the rows inside that table.

You can do this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@width='270']")).findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody > tr"));
```

`list` will now contain each `tr` (row) within that `table`.

Comment: Or, more simply, `List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@width='270']/tbody/tr"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@width='270']/tr"));
```

Try findElements() instead.

Comment: Edit:Just realized I had forgotten to add the tr at the end

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid XPaths, when possible, because they are slower and more error prone. I don't know how stable it is to use the table width as the locator but since you used it, I'll use it also.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table[width='270'] > tbody > tr"));
System.out.println(list.size());
```

[CSS Selectors reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)